# GCC compiler can't find my file in VS Code

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

**Problem Summary:** Attempting to compile C code in Visual Studio Code terminal using the line `gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world` and encountering the return:

> gcc.exe: error: hello_world.c: No such file or directory
> gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
> compilation terminated.

**What I've Tried:** Including the entire file path in the command, so it becomes   `gcc C:/User/user/Desktop/coding_stuff/C/csci_a/hello_world.c -o hello_world`

Clean reinstall of VS code. Copying the c_cpp_properties.json, launch.json, settings.json, tasks.json files from someone whose VS code was working perfectly and altering the compiler path in those files to where my gcc is installed (written as "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" in the files.

**The Code:**

[Using an image of the code since using Ctrl+K doesn't format the code the way it's supposed to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3JhY.png)

I feel like this has to be a very simple fix, and the fact I can't seem to find anyone else having this problem means I'm probably doing something very basic very wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is controlled by your `tasks.json` file in the .vscode folder according to the documentation:  [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: My tasks.json is line for line what is listed on that page, other than the compiler directory, which has been changed to reflect my compiler directory. Should I have changed something else?

Comment: I think we need to see the terminal output from the build as text.

Comment: gcc.exe: error: hello_world.c: No such file or directory 
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files 
compilation terminated.

^This is what is output by the terminal.

Comment: Couldn't you use the `cd` command?

Comment: The terminal should have a `cd command`

Comment: I'm very new to this stuff, thank you both.